# How to update particlesjs colors in particlesConfig dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, particles.js

Okay, so I am making a website and was able to setup shifting between darkmode and light mode using react styled-components and change the colors for body, and other elements using css

Only problem is I can't seem to find a way to update the colors in the particlesconfig.json

Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

A year late, but for future readers, particles.js exposes a `window.pJSDom` array. You can use it change the parameters and refresh the particles.

```
pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.color.value = '#ffffff';
pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.line_linked.color = '#ffffff';
pJSDom[0].pJS.fn.particlesRefresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help a bit more if you upload how to set up the particles in your project. In my case I also have light mode and dark mode, it worked for me by creating 02 particle files (particlesLight and particlesDark) and alternating them with a useState depending on the theme, here's an example:

```
const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
const [particles, setParticles] = useState(particlesDark);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    switch (theme) {
      case "dark":
        setParticles(particlesDark);
        break;
      case "light":
        setParticles(particlesLight);
        break;
    }
  }, [theme]);

  return <Particles options={particles} init={particlesInit} />;
```

I hope it helps someone else!